# Users and User Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I'm looking @ my dependencies model and my users_session class is the only one that has no dependencies. Should there be any for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how my UserSession class looks in an app successfully using authlogic:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

and no, it doesn't contain any explicit relationships. The logic is instead contained in `Authlogic::Session::Base`. You don't need to worry about any relationships.